# Why don't my thinkpad ultrabase 3 usb ports work when I dock x220?

Tags: 16.04, usb, thinkpad, docking

I have ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS installed on thinkpad x220. I Just purchased an ultrabase 3 docking station, and after I dock the thinkpad, the usb ports on the dock don't work and the little red light on the dock does not light up, however the thinkpad does see that there is AC power and the dvd drive in ultrabay works.  I'm not using external monitor so I haven't checked if vga or display port is working.  The main thing is that I want the usb ports to work for my keyboard and mouse.

I have found that if I sleep the thinkpad and then resume after docked the red light will illuminate and usually the usb ports will then work.  So that is a workaround, but annoying.

Is there a known issue with the kernel in 16.04?  Also, how best to diagnose?

Comment: I just tried with an ubuntu 18.04 live usb and the behavior is exactly the same.   I don't believe it is the ultrabase's fault since it works fine if the laptop is booted already docked or after sleep/resume.  But if this is a linux kernel issue I'm surprised I don't find complaints of it affecting others.   If anyone reading this has an ultrabase 3, can you confirm that usb ports work after docking?

Comment: Run `journalctl -f` then connect to the dock. Interesting log messages may result. Or `starttime="$(date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')"`, then connect to dock, then `journalctl --since="$starttime"`

Comment: Thx @waltinator.  output [here](https://pastebin.com/zExWKeFB) since I couldn't figure out how to format properly in a comment.

Comment: Edit your post, paste in a few, carefully selected lines, select them, and click the `{}` symbol just above the edit window. Or, go to the Help section of AskUbuntu and get a better explanation

Comment: Do not post logvomit - most of the log entries over there do not pertain to USB, and they lack context. You asked "How best to diagnose", not "fix it for me"

Comment: you gave me a command to run.  I ran it, and posted the output, which is not even especially long.  if that bothers you, so be it.

Comment: re "click the {} symbol just above the edit window", there are no symbols above this comment textbox in my (chrome/ubuntu) browser whether text is selected or not.  re help section:  I previously did that, also googled, and tried every suggested method, including ```, ~~~, and 4 spaces indentation.  nothing worked.    thx for trying, but I wouldn't have used pastebin if it were working as documented.  oh well.